# how to hash a bitcoin address for transactions?

Tags: address, hash, p2sh

can someone tell me **how bitcoin hash a btc address?**

when you try to hash it on [this website](https://bitcointools.site/tool/address-to-hash), you will get the same result as down below

```
Bitcoin Address : 1JKRgG4F7k1b7PbAhQ7heEuV5aTJDpK9TS
Result (Hash 160) : bdf63990d6dc33d705b756e13dd135466c06b3b5
```

but when i convert the address to ripemd160,  i got a completely different result

```
3da397753d32cea0858334e36fc58ae53f8c2529
```

so **how do i get the same result as the first one?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same result you must decode the address, which means convert the base58 to hexadecimal.

**1JKRgG4F7k1b7PbAhQ7heEuV5aTJDpK9TS** becomes **00bdf63990d6dc33d705b756e13dd135466c06b3b55850d39d**

Where:

- 00 -> mainnet
- **bdf63990d6dc33d705b756e13dd135466c06b3b5** -> hash160 of
  public key
- 5850d39d -> checksum

Comment: thank you sir, this really help me out

Comment: but how can i convert the address to hexadecimel?

Comment: Quite simple on this tool https://appdevtools.com/base58-encoder-decoder. You can also create an python file, import base58, then print(base58.b58decode(address).hex())

Comment: Whoaaaa thankk youu sirrrr, i really appreciate thisss....thankss a lootttt